# Rising when saying Elokeinu in a zimmun

Tags: halacha, bentching, standing-sitting, zimun

I have seen many people, among them talmidei chachamim, rise out of their seat when saying God's name (Elokeinu) during a zimmun of 10 people.

Is there a source for this behavior?

Comment: any famous talmidei chachamim? I've never seen anyone (of repute) do this